# unittest.mock Patch() vs monkeypatch

Tags: python, pytest

I am converting old unittest test cases to pytest. 
I'm currently stuck on converting this unittest line to monkeypatch function:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

patch('app.modle.addres.create, side_effect=create(add.address)):
```

would monkeypatch even be the right module to use?

Comment: Don't get confused by the `unittest` parent package. `mock` is universal.

Comment: so i could still use the patch function with pytest instead of using monkeypatch??

Comment: Why do you want to convert from `unittest.mock.patch` to `pytest.monkeypatch`?

Comment: See also: [Advice request: monkeypatch vs mock.patch](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4576)

Answer (score -12, accepted):

Just install `mock` package (`pip install mock`) and do

```
from mock import patch
```

Comment: Why? The `mock` package from PyPI is the same as standard library `unittest.mock`. The only difference is that it allows you to use a newer (or older) version than the one bundled with your Python.